# Is it possible to use django generic-class based view with a database view as model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my problem, i'm building a q&a website, i have **questions, tags, category** as models. I want to use django generic-class based view in other to display the list of questions in database.

I have already done that using the Question class, but i don't have all the details that belong to another models like question category and tags so i decided to create a database view.

Here is my models module

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField




class QuestionCategory(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, help_text="question")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.FileField()


    def __str__(self):

        return self.name

class QuestionTag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    nb_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    anonymously = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    details = RichTextUploadingField(null = True)
    #une question appartient à une seule catégorie
    category = models.ForeignKey('QuestionCategory', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionTag, help_text="Selectionnez un tag pour cette question")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('question-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Answer(models.Model):
    nb_upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    nb_downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    nb_views = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    details = RichTextUploadingField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Answer " + str(self.id) 


class AnswerComment(models.Model):
    nb_upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    nb_downvotes = models.IntegerField(default =0)
    details = models.TextField()
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class View360Question(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    nb_views = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    last_edited_at = models.DateTimeField()
    nb_answers = models.IntegerField()
    tags = models.TextField()
    category_name = models.TextField()
    category_id = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "qanda_view360question"
```

And here is my views module

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Question, View360Question, QuestionCategory, Answer, QuestionTag, AnswerComment

# Create your views here.

def index(request):

    #on récupère le nombre de questions
    num_questions = Question.objects.all().count()

    #nombre de questions anonymes
    num_anonym_questions = Question.objects.filter(anonymously= True).count()

    #nombre de réponses
    num_answers = Answer.objects.all().count()

    #nombre de Catégories
    num_categories = QuestionCategory.objects.all().count() 

    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        context={'num_questions': num_questions, 'num_anonym_questions': num_anonym_questions,
        'num_answers': num_answers, 'num_categories': num_categories}
    )



def qaIndex(request):

    return render(request, 'qa.html')


def categoriesIndex(request):

    return render(request, 'categories_index.html')


class View360QuestionListView(generic.ListView):
    model = View360Question
    template_name = 'questions/questions_list.html'
```

In View360QuestionListView when i change the model to Question it fetch items from database, but when i come back to View360Question which is the view i created, i always fetch an empty array, but in database the view returns items.

Comment: "a kind of clown of stackoverflow" hehe, you made an involuntary nice joke.

Comment: This is an interesting question but there's a bit too much details.  I'd suggest editing your code down to a smaller model and seeing if you still are having the error... if not, you might have answered your own question.

Comment: Post the content of `questions_list.html`. You say "In View360QuestionListView when i change the model to Question it fetch items from database", but those models have different field names, so in your template they should be call differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Guillermo chamorro said, the problem was in my template
instead of using the viewname_list i used question_list.
Thank you.